# Print Prime Numbers and Reversed Number

Tags: c

A number and a reversed number form a pair. If both numbers are prime numbers, we call it a reversed prime number pair. For instance, 13 and 31 is a 2 digit reversed prime number pair, 107 and 701 is a 3 digit reversed prime number pairs.

Write a program to output all n (2<=n<=5) digit reversed prime number pairs. If the input is less than 2 or greater than 5, output "Wrong input." and terminate the program. While ouputting , every 5 pairs form a new line, and only output the pair in which the first number is smaller than the second number.

Input: 1
Output: Wrong input.
Input: 3
Output:
(107,701)(113,311)(149,941)(157,751)(167,761)
(179,971)(199,991)(337,733)(347,743)(359,953)
(389,983)(709,907)(739,937)(769,967)
There are 14 results.

Can anyone give me hints how to do this?

I know how to determine if a number is a reversed prime number, but i couldn't understand how to complete this challenge from my friend

```
#include <stdio.h>
 

int checkPrime(int n) {  
  int i, isPrime = 1;  
  
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {  
    isPrime = 0;  
  }  
  else {  
    for(i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i) {  
      if(n % i == 0) {  
        isPrime = 0;  
        break;  
      }  
    }  
  }  
  
  return isPrime;  
}  
int main (void)
{
    int a, reverse = 0, remainder, flag=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int temp = a;
    while (temp!=0) {
        remainder = temp%10;
        reverse = reverse*10 + remainder;
        temp/=10;
    }
    if (checkPrime(a)==1)  {
        if (checkPrime(reverse)==1){
            printf("YES\n");
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if (flag==0)
    printf("NO\n");
    }
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is a place for asking **specific** questions. It is not a place to ask for general help or advice, or for "hints". You may want to read this for further information: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/12149471)

Comment: Please specify with which part of the assignment you are having trouble. In your question, you state that the problem is not determining whether a number is a reversed prime number. What exactly is the problem, then?

Answer (score -3):

This will be the correct solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_N 100000

int *primes;
int num_primes;

void init_primes() {
    int sqrt_max_n = sqrt(MAX_N);
    primes = (int *) malloc(sqrt_max_n / 2 * sizeof(int));
    num_primes = 0;
    primes[num_primes] = 2;
    num_primes++;
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt_max_n; i += 2) {
        bool is_prime = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < num_primes; j++) {
            if (i % primes[j] == 0) {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_prime) {
            primes[num_primes] = i;
            num_primes++;
        }
    }
}

int is_prime(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_primes; i++) {
        if (primes[i] == n) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (n % primes[i] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int reverse(int n) {
    int reversed_n = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        reversed_n = reversed_n * 10 + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return reversed_n;
}

int main() {
    init_primes();

    int n;
    printf("Enter n (2 <= n <= 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n < 2 || n > 5) {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int min = (int) pow(10, n - 1);
    int max = (int) pow(10, n) - 1;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        if (is_prime(i)) {
            int reversed_i = reverse(i);
            if (i < reversed_i && is_prime(reversed_i)) {
                printf("(%d %d)", i, reversed_i);
                count++;
                if (count % 5 == 0) {
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After testing this code I get the same result what you need:

```
Enter n (2 <= n <= 5): 3
(107 701) (113 311) (149 941) (157 751) (167 761)
(179 971) (199 991) (337 733) (347 743) (359 953)
(389 983) (709 907) (739 937) (769 967)
```

The **init_primes** method caches all the required prime numbers until the sqrt of your limit to a dynamic array.

The **is_prime** method uses that cache for detecting whether a number is prime or not.

Comment: So free homework?

Comment: Come on, let this kid have some fun.

Comment: DV for same reason as Harris, and more. No feedback given to OP regarding their code. Code calc's all primes to 99999+1 (5 digits) before user makes erroneous entry and processing discarded. What if user only wanted 2 digits? or 3? Then, all values, including multiples of 2, are checked as being prime... Nice formatting but really bad code (whether it works or not.) No recognition that `malloc()` may return a NULL pointer... Using floating point functions for an integer algorithm... Definitely a low quality answer.